# Jquery HTML() function - how to include selector Html

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

I suspect this is a really stupid question, but when you call the Html() function in JQuery it returns the selected nodes inner Html. Is there anyway of including the selected note in the returned Html? For example on the following HTML

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
```

this call `$('div.demo-container').html();` returns

```
<div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
```

How do I get it to return

```
<div class="demo-container">
  <div class="demo-box">Demonstration Box</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap a copy of it in a boring div and get the HTML of that:

```
var str = $('div.demo-container').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this extension, example from [here](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/)

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
   return (s)
   ? this.before(s).remove()
   : jQuery("&lt;p&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
$('#myTag').outerHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.demo-container').parent().html() //Only works in this specific situation
```

or

```
$('div.demo-container')[0].outerHTML; //Only works in IE and Chrome
```

Comment: isn't outerHTML an IE only property?

Comment: `.parent().html()` will give the wrong result if `div.demo-container` has siblings.

Comment: @MorganTiley it works in chrome as well, doesn't seem to be supported by firefox

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
$('div.demo-container').parent().html();
```

Comment: Gives the wrong results if `div.demo-container` has siblings.

Comment: gives the right result to his example :)